# Sending json object using HttpsUrlConnection in android

Tags: android, json, httpsurlconnection

I am sending a json object to the server using `HttpsUrlConnection` as following

```
try{ 
    JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();

    jobj.put("UserName","demo1");
    jobj.put("Password","demo1");
    Log.e("json string :",jobj.toString());

    byte[] postData = jobj.toString().getBytes();

    URL url = new URL("https://services.myovs.com/TokenService/Token");

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

    out.write(postData);
    out.close();

    String temp = ((HttpsURLConnection)conn).getResponseMessage();
    Log.e("response  :",temp);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();   
}
```

and

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
                String authType) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
                String authType) {}
    }
};
```

but its getting an exception like

> 08-26 20:12:30.179: WARN/System.err(12477): java.io.IOException: Hostname 'services.myovs.com' was not verified
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:199)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:391)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at com.example.httpconnection.Main.httpMethode(Main.java:69)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at com.example.httpconnection.Main.onCreate(Main.java:27)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   08-26 20:12:30.187: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) > 08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   08-26 20:12:30.195: WARN/System.err(12477):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: i edited the response please find that

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it's not an exception. Instead it's a warning written to the log including a stacktrace.

The warning indicates that the connection is not secure because the hostname could not be verified. It has to do with the HTTPS (as opposed to a HTTP) connection you're using. The server probably doesn't have a certificate issued by a publicly known certificate authority.